# basic telnet script to copy to flash drive

Tags: ansible, backup, telnet, cisco

I am trying to use ansible to telnet into cisco switches and apply a copy startup-config disk0 command.

Ansible seems to never be able to pass 
  (?i)"Destination filename": "work please" through the expect command

```
    ---
    - hosts: all
      gather_facts: false
      connection: local
      tasks:
      - name: telnet,login and execute command
        ignore_errors: true
        expect:
        command: telnet "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        responses:
          (?i)password: "{{ password}}"
          (?i)#: copy startup-config disk0
          (?i)"Destination filename": "{{ lookup('pipe','date') }"
        echo: yes
      register: telnet_output
```

What i am getting as an output

```
ansible-playbook 2.7.6
```

config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Oct 30 2018, 23:45:53) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
/var/lib/awx/projects/6500/hosts did not meet host_list requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
/var/lib/awx/projects/6500/hosts did not meet script requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected

PLAYBOOK: copy-startup.yml *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in copy-startup.yml

PLAY [all] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [telnet,login and execute command] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /var/lib/awx/projects/6500/copy-startup.yml:6
fatal: [66.90.19.18]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "telnet \"66.90.19.18\"", "delta": "0:00:30.370396", "end": "2019-02-12 10:09:41.473716", "msg": "command exceeded timeout", "rc": null, "start": "2019-02-12 10:09:11.103320", "stdout": "Trying 66.90.19.18...\r\r\nConnected to 66.90.19.18.\r\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\r\n\r\n\r\nUser Access Verification\r\n\r\nPassword: \r\nLAB-6500-SUP2T#copy startup-config disk0\r\nDestination filename [disk0]? ", "stdout_lines": ["Trying 66.90.19.18...", "", "Connected to 66.90.19.18.", "", "Escape character is '^]'.", "", "", "", "User Access Verification", "", "Password: ", "LAB-6500-SUP2T#copy startup-config disk0", "Destination filename [disk0]? "]}
...ignoring

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
66.90.19.18                : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0

It seems to never want to write the Destination Filename[disk0]? 
Any ideas

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How can i pass over   (?i)"Destination filename": "work please" it never seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

`(?i)"Destination filename"` matches for string with double quotes.

You need:

```
responses:
    '(?i)password': "{{ password}}"
    '(?i)#': copy startup-config disk0
    '(?i)Destination filename': "{{ lookup('pipe','date') }"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   ---
   - hosts: '6500'
   gather_facts: true
   connection: local
   tasks:

   - name: telnet,login and execute command
     ignore_errors: true
     expect:
        command: telnet "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        responses:
          (?i)Password: {{ password }}
         (?i)Destination filename [disk0]? : "{{ lookup('pipe','date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M') }} {{ inventory_hostname }}"
         (?i)#: copy startup-config disk0
         (?i){{COMMAND}}: exit
       echo: yes
      register: telnet_output
```

This seems to be the best solution to what I need. I changed the order of operations and it was rocking,